# How to build Retrofit API from property file?

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2

Is it possible to build a retrofit API where path, fields and its values are taken from a `property` file located inside `assets` folder? Example:

```
interface StatusAPI {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api path")
    fun readRawHtml(
            @Field("arg1 key") arg1: String = "arg1 value",
            @Field("arg2 key") arg2: String = "arg2 value",
            @Field("arg3 key") arg3: String = getArg3Value(),
    ): Single<String>

    private fun getArg3() = "arg3 value"

}

url.path = /path%20to%20api
form.key.arg1 = arg1key
form.value.arg1 = arg1value
form.key.arg2 = arg2key
form.value.arg2 = arg2value
form.key.arg3 = arg3key
form.value.arg3 = arg3value
```

P.S.: I known how to read the property file and take its values, also I'm using Dagger2 as DI container, if retrofit API was a class and I could inject a component capable to read the property files inside it would be perfect, but since the Retrofit API is built in an interface, I don't know if what I want can be accomplished.

Comment: You can do to manipulate of URL dynamically. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Retrofit uses dynamic proxy and requires an interface.

Comment: It was just out of curiosity. So, I guess the best option would be using a constant file where all the values are initially defined

Comment: What? It uses dynamic proxy, not annotation processing - either way, you need an `interface` to make that work.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ok, sorry for that. I updated the response.